# How to bind to ngFor

Tags: html, angular, events

I'm trying to creating an application that shows different events but when I load the webpage, it is empty and the console says 'Can't bind to 'ngForEvent' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. How do I fix that so the events are seen on the webpage?

events-list.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core'

@Component({
selector: 'events-list',
template: `
<div>
    <h1>Upcoming Angular Events</h1>
    <hr/>
    <div class="row">
        <div *ngFor="Let event of events" class="col-md-5">
            <event-thumbnail [event]="event"></event-thumbnail>
        </div>
    </div>    
</div>    
`
})
export class EventsListComponent {
events = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Angular Connect',
      date: '9/26/2036',
      time: '10:00 am',
      price: 599.99,
      imageUrl: '/assets/images/angularconnect-shield.png',
      location: {
        address: '1057 DT',
        city: 'London',
        country: 'England'
      },
       sessions: [
           {
             id: 1,
             name: "Using Angular 4 Pipes",
             presenter: "Peter Bacon Darwin",
             duration: 1,
             level: "Intermediate",
             abstract: `Learn all about the new pipes in Angular 4, both 
             how to write them, and how to get the new AI CLI to write 
             them for you. Given by the famous PBD, president of Angular 
             University (formerly Oxford University)`,
             voters: ['bradgreen', 'igorminar', 'martinfowler']
             }
            }
           }
```

Comment: I suggest you to replace "Let" by "let" (in lower case). Else, for me, it's good

Answer (score 0):

you can use @Input decorator for this problem.

https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs

this link also help to solve the problem.